# Why NServiceBus performance is affected by SignalR connection

Tags: signalr, nservicebus, asp.net-core-signalr

I had a web service which has been using `NServiceBus` message handling between `controller` and `domain logic`. For a new functionality, I have to implement `signalR webRT` communication between clients and server. But there are some performance problems. I thought that, the problems occur from my design defect but I couldn't detect reason of the problem, yet.

Before `SignalR` integration, my web service was responsing in 20-30ms. But when a `signalR` client (only one client is enough) is connected to my web service, the responce time becomes to around 10000ms. When I remove `NServiceBus` implementation between my `controller` and `domainlogic` (directly operate my logic in controller and return) the responce time again down to reasonable value (around 20-30ms).

My web service is a .net core project. And I'm using long-pool threading mechanism for signalR.

Comment: 10 seconds delay sounds off. Without seeing code, hard to say what's happening. Any chance to share a simple repro?

Comment: @SeanFeldman, I can share my source within a call. I can't share it public. But I can collect some metrics from my rabbitmq which can help you and share them. Is there any possibility to reach you?

Comment: I didn't mean to share you specific code, but a reproduction of the code to demonstrate the issue. Without seeing what's happening it's virtually impossible to suggest what to look into. Alternatively, if it's your production code, suggest you reach out to [support](https://particular.net/support).